# Blending objects with eachother but not with background actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, blending

I have a number of objects (represented as DisplayObjects) that i wish to blend with eachother.

However behind these objects there is a background that i do not want to involve in the blending.

So basically i want to blend these objects with eachother and afterwards use the result of this blending as a new DisplayObject (for example to put it on top of a randomly colored background).

So what i have is:

```
var obj1:DisplayObject = getFirstObj();
var obj2:DisplayObject = getSecObj();
var background:DisplayObject = getBackground();

obj1.blendMode = BlendMode.ADD;
obj2.blendMode = BlendMode.ADD;
```

A first attempt i tried was putting these objects into a common DisplayObjectContainer hoping that blending mode would only be relative to all objects contained by the same DisplayObjectContainer, but this does not seem to be the case.

```
var objectsPool:Sprite = new Sprite();
objectsPool.addChild( obj1 );
objectsPool.addChild( obj2 );

addChild( background );
addchild( objectsPool );
```

So that diddent get me anywhere.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: changed DisplayObjectContainer to Sprite in the last code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the objects into a container, and remove it from the stage, you can then draw it with the BitmapData class and create a new Bitmap object representing the combination.  This will have a transparent background, and it's blendMode will be normal, allowing you to use it on the background.

```
var obj1:DisplayObject = getFirstObj();
var obj2:DisplayObject = getSecObj();
var background:DisplayObject = getBackground();

obj1.blendMode = BlendMode.ADD;
obj2.blendMode = BlendMode.ADD;

var objectsPool:DisplayObjectContainer = new DisplayObjectContainer();
objectsPool.addChild( obj1 );
objectsPool.addChild( obj2 );

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(objectsPool.width,objectsPool.height,true,0);
bmd.draw(objectsPool);

var drawnObject:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);

addChild( background );
addchild( drawnObject );
```

(untested code, good luck)

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thanks! The code is not runable because my own code wasent (I noticed that DisplayObjectContainer is an abstract class afterwards so that should be a Sprite instance for example), your addition works nicely through.

Answer (score 0):

Rather going to the effort of drawing a Bitmap yourself, there are options that cause Flash to rasterize a layer and it's children automatically.  Try:

```
container.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

or try:

```
container.blendMode = "layer";
```

or try:

```
container.filters = [new GlowFilter(0,0,0,0)];
```

Any of those options should cause the children to render into a Bitmap under the hood, invalidating their individual blend modes/effects on the background.